Started Yaale ve'yavo on rosh chodesh Iyar/Cheshvan and then lost concentration
The halacha is, that until one has accustomed themselves to repeating a phrase in prayer (e.g. mashiv haruach) for 30 consecutive days, OR they have repeated it 90 times, if they cannot remember whether they mentioned said phrase, we have to assume they did not say it (and would therefore have to repeat the amida).
Imagine a scenario where someone knows that they began Ya'ale veyavo on Rosh chodesh Iyar or Rosh Chodesh Cheshvan, but they cannot remember if they said "beyom Rosh Hachodesh hazeh" or "beyom Chag Hasukot/Chag Hamatzot Hazeh".
Is the 30-day/90-reps rule absolute, or only lechumra? In other words, are we concerned that having said "Beyom Chag Ha____" for 8 days straight in the recent past, the habit may have become ingrained and will therefore require a new amida, or is anything less than 30 days of a different version of prayer insignificant?
(I ask about those 2 Rosh Chodesh's (Roshei Chadashim?) because any other Rosh Chodesh is more than 30 days after a different version of ya'aleh veyavo was said.)

I don't understand. No one ever says Yaaleh veYavo for 30 days straight so you are never (halachicaly) accustomed to saying it any way.

You are never conclusively accustomed to saying it, true. but maybe we need to consider that you are more accustomed to saying "beyom Rosh hachodesh hazeh" than "beyom Hamatzot/Hasukot Hazeh" (we say it approx 18 times/year). The 30 day rule can only require a new shemona esrei, not free you from the safek that you said the wrong thing... or maybe not

Rosh Chodesh is the most common, but most Yaaleh veYavo in the year are not Rosh Chodesh.

This is a surprisingly interesting question because of what it is balancing:

We don't say Yaaleh V'Yavo (YV"Y) often enough for it to become habitual that we can build the habit of saying it right, so maybe we should repeat it if we don't know if we said it correctly
It also isn't said in a place where we have a previous habit in place, so there's no reason to presume that we said the wrong one either, so maybe we shouldn't repeat.

Therefore, we need a third principle and that is going to be: did we intend to say YV"Y with the correct holiday in mind or not? In most cases, we can assume that if one remembered to say it, they remembered to say it for the correct occasion.
So, the conclusion is that, if one has finished and moved on already, one does not repeat it* but if one realises right after (still in Retzei**), he can repeat, as concludes the Mishnah Berura 114:38:

(לח) בחזקת שהזכיר וכו' - ואם ברור לו שהיה בדעתו לזכור מעין המאורע
[לענין הזכרה ושאלה ויעלה ויבא וכה"ג] בתוך התפלה ולאחר זמן מופלג נפל
ספק בלבו אם זכר בתפלה או לא אין צריך לחזור ואם נתעורר הספק מיד אחר
התפלה יש לחזור [מור וקציעה ומגן גבורים]:
It is presumed that he mentioned, etc. – If it is clear to him that he had the intention to recall the relevant occasion [regarding
insertions such as mention of rain, requests, Yaaleh Veyavo, and
similar] during the prayer, and after some time, he
begins to doubt whether he actually mentioned it during the prayer or
not, he does not need to repeat the prayer. However, if the doubt
arises immediately after the prayer, he can repeat it [Mor
U'Ketzia and Magen Gibborim].

*Obviously, in the rare case where one had a brain freeze and thought it was Pesach or Rosh Chodesh instead of Sukkot (or was completely unaware that it was a special occasion and said YV"Y by mistake), then one should probably repeat - but please CYLOR for practical applications of the above principles.
** See Kaf Hachaim s'k 48, explaining the Mor U'Ketzia

This source is addressing a slightly different case where a while later you don't remember if you said anything at all. Here it can be right away and you know you said the paragraph but you don't know what holiday you mentioned

@DoubleAA a notable objection, but my theory is based on the words "מעין המאורע" which I feel strongly one can infer our case from, and it's also a weaker case, that's covered by the stronger.

@DoubleAA if it is right away, then one can repeat without any loss of safek bracha lehakel (taking into account that Kaf Hachaim's limitations on "right away"). In other cases, one can assume that if one remembered it was Yom Tov, one doesn't have to repeat YV"Y, surely one doesn't have to repeat it if one remembers saying YV"Y. I believe this is also directly explained this way for our exact case in Halichot Shlomo, but will need to confirm when I have it in front of me. The only thing left unanswered by this logic is if one MUST repeat, when it is "right away".

Suppose you know you started Yaaleh veYavo and the next thing you know you're bowing and saying Moadim Anarchy Lach. By what right can you assume you said the correct holiday?

@DoubleAA we can assume you said it correctly based on your intention to say the correct festival, whose identity you knew. Presuming that is a typo, and you didn't find yourself saying "when it comes to moadim, for You it is anarchy!" in which case you definitely didn't have the right intention

Intention to say the right thing later is not sufficient to justify the assumption, as seen from intention to say morid hageshem before 30 days

@DoubleAA a proper comparison is the case where one can't remember if one said morid hageshem or not, but one does definitely remember explicitly intending to say it during the tefilla, beforehand (and one is now doubting right after finishing - Kaf Hachaim). This is even stronger, because not only do we have proof one definitely intended to say YV"Y (as he did say it! you are asking if correctly:), on top of that, we have this principle that one was בדעתו לזכור מעין המאורע. If not, see first asterisk of my answer. Anyway, gotta go. Ill see if I can find that Halichot Shlomo to end all kashes

Also with regards to moridh hageshem, we have the problem of habit, which we don't have here

+1 for an excellent summary of the question. I agree with Double AA though, I don't think your proof is conclusive
